# Can't hit breakpoint in program.main Blazor Client wasm

Tags: c#, settings, blazor, program-entry-point, start-process

Create a basic Blazor App, I'm trying to debug the main/start method of my app.
Mainly to check the objects I'm injecting and primarily getting the configurations from appsettings.json.

I've also added the in lauchSettings.json the json setting for browser debug but no success.

```
"inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
```

I've checked on google but not many solution in relation to the Program.Main() breakpoints.
Any suggestions?

[image]

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);



        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/") });
        builder.Services.AddScoped<DashboardDataService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<TrTradingSignalBotApiService>();
        builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: [The documentation that describes this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#breakpoints-in-oninitializedasync-not-hit-1)

Ok, this is ugly, but presumably you only want it as a one-off, so just wait a few seconds - for me on my desktop, 2 seconds is enough - it gives the debugger time to attach. Once you find the delay that works for you, it works.

Note, I couldn't get `Debugger.IsAttached` or `Debugger.Break()` to work, so you have to set a breakpoint in the editor.

Wrap the delay in `#if DEBUG...#endif` to make sure you don't release with that in place.

```csharp
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
#if DEBUG        
        await Task.Delay(2000);
#endif
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/") });
        builder.Services.AddScoped<DashboardDataService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<TrTradingSignalBotApiService>();
        builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this before and it did not work. Did it again now and it's actually working. Thanks

Comment: Amazing this works, thanks! I had to try a longer timeout, but it worked nonetheless.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me, even with 10x longer timeout (I'm on an extremely fast machine)