# Unable to hit breakpoints in Blazor WASM

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am trying to debug a Blazor WebAssembly app but get the following message when trying to set breakpoints:

[image: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unbound breakpoint]

If I do the action that would hit the breakpoint, visual studio instead opens a new tab that says `Unable to retrieve source content (Unable to retrieve source content)`. I have the same issue in a separate blazor server app, as well as the sample template that is provided when first creating a blazor project (counter.razor and fetchdata.razor).

Here is the info on the app:
Target Framework: .NET 5.0 (Current)
Authentication Type: None
Configure for HTTPS: True
ASP.NET Core hosted: False
Progressive Web Application: True

I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.4.

My .csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.5" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My launchSettings.json file is:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59417",
      "sslPort": 44389
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116749/cant-hit-breakpoint-in-program-main-blazor-client-wasm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469337/blazor-wasm-doesnt-hit-breakpoint).
I also checked https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-3-release-now-available/, even though it is a year old.
I restarted Visual studio multiple times, deleted the .vs file, restarted my comp, but the same issue.

Comment: Where the breakpoint locates? If it is set in the async Task(ex: `async Task Main(string[] args)`), you need to follow this document to debug it : [How Do I Debug Async Code in Visual Studio?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-do-i-debug-async-code-in-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the error was that my solution path had a "#' in a folder name. This error was discussed https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22036 which apparently was never resolved if you follow the thread.

Comment: Thank god for this response, I renamed my folder where the project was from "C# projects" to "CSharp projects" the break point was getting hit