# Blazor WASM Breakpoints not being hit

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm following the TimCorey 'TimCoRetailManager' course. It contains the Counter.Razor page (same one you see in the project template) in the WASM project.

I've put breakpoints in the @code and they are never hit.

I've tried this delay: [Can't hit breakpoint in program.main Blazor Client wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116749/cant-hit-breakpoint-in-program-main-blazor-client-wasm)

I've tried deleting the .vs solution folder, reloading the solution and rebooting as recommended elsewhere.

None of my folders have a # in the name.

If I create a new WASM project it hits the breakpoints fine.

How can I get them working? Thx.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem. Make sure you are on the latest patch release of the SDK 6.0.202. If you want to have a look at working config, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574). It's for Edge though, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got this error at it's like David Fuchs said. I had updated package in a Blazor Client project from .NET Core 5 to 6 but left a few others still pointing to 5. This caused this issue of the breakpoint.
After I updated and consolidate all packages to 6 the Breakpoints were triggered again.

Package I updated to .net 6 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer
Package still in version 5 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today. The solution for me was to use [dotnet-core-uninstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows) to remove all .NET SDKs and runtimes, reboot my PC, and then reinstall .NET 6.0.

Through basic testing I was able to determine that I could debug a Blazor WASM app created with `dotnet new blazorwasm` when targeting .NET 5.0, but not when targeting .NET 6.0. Both apps were completely boilerplate, and I added a breakpoint on the same line you did in Counter.razor.

Solutions I tried included repairing the .NET 6.0 SDK, switching between Edge and Chrome, and reinstalling Visual Studio, but still couldn't get it to work on .NET 6.0 until I wiped out all the SDKs and runtimes and started fresh.

Comment: thanks - and wow seems drastic. I can debug new blazor WASM apps fine so I don't think it's a system level issue?!

Comment: Try comparing the .csproj files between your working and non-working project - I have a feeling they'll be targeting different .NET versions. I honestly don't know what is causing the problem, but I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the .NET runtime/SDK installation.

Comment: pretty extreme, but have no choice. WASM breakpoints had been hit just fine, then, suddenly not! Another visual studio 2022 update bug. Time to reinstall everything... AGAIN

Comment: Unfortunately, uninstalling everything, SDKs and VS (100% of it) had no effect. I believe VS 2022 17.3.2 and up has a bug in it (since it does not work in new projects nor after complete reinstall)

Comment: @MC9000, did you ever figure it out? I'm on 17.8.6 with .NET 8 and this is happening to me.

Comment: I totally forgot all the steps I took. Sorry! Usually you have to do the annual uninstall/reinstall to get anything to work.  I ended up setting up my dev environment in a VM. I saved the baseline version, so if VS becomes corrupted (as it ALWAYS does - randomly) again, I can copy the baseline VM and run a fresh copy (after updates, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Tried almost everything, then I looked at the cs.proj file and noticed this property group

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
<Optimize>False</Optimize>
```

I tried removing it, rebuilding, and ran it again then BOOM debugging worked and the breakpoint was hit. Hopefully this saves someone else some time.

Comment: This answer was flagged 8 months ago and because of that I deleted it. However after running into this same problem again I stumbled upon this post and saw my deleted answer. It worked for me again so I am adding it back.

Comment: I'll have to try that the next time this aggravating problem arises.  It would be nice to know how/why this keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today and the solution for me was to change the Web Browser to Edge.[image: screenshot of VS UI changing the Web Browser to Edge: from the dropdown near the 'start debugging' button, select 'Web Browser' and then 'Microsoft Edge']

Comment: Also worth totally clearing browser history

Comment: Does clearing it 100 times count? 

Comment: i am on 17.8.0 VS 2022. i noticed this with a new .NET 7 WASM project. breakpoints are hit when i start the .client project (but then i'm missing the server!) when running the .server project in debug mode, only when auto-starting EDGE breakpoints are hit, not in Firefox or Chrome. WHY? HOW can i fix those browsers?